# No test found message using Espresso

Tags: android, junit4, android-espresso

I have a simple test in Espresso.

```
public class MainActivityTest {


@Rule
public final ActivityRule<MainActivity> main = new ActivityRule<>(MainActivity.class);

@Test
public void shouldBeAbleToLaunchMainScreen(){
    onView(withText("Hello")).check(ViewAssertions.matches(isDisplayed()));
   }
}
```

However,I can't run it. To help understand I am showing you the following picture.

[image: My Tests]

Why do I get this message?

**Error:Instrumentation runner class not specified**.

I also declared it the gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "theo.testing.androidespresso"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}

  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),    
        'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions{
    exclude 'LICENCE.txt'
}

}

dependencies {
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
 androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0'

 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
 androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
 contrib:2.2.2') {
    // Necessary to avoid version conflicts
    exclude group: 'javax.inject'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
  }


}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

please take a look at `Espresso` setup instruction: https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/setup/

Especially at this part:

> ### Download Espresso
>
> - Make sure you have installed the latest `Android Support Repository` under `Extras` (see
>     [instructions](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/downloads/index.html)).
> - Open your app’s `build.gradle` file. This is usually not the top-level `build.gradle` file but `app/build.gradle`.
> - Add the following lines inside dependencies:
>
>   ```
>    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
>    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
>   ```
>
> See the
>   (downloads)[https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/downloads/index.html]
>   section for more `artifacts` (`espresso-contrib`, `espresso-web`,
>   etc.)

You're already missing these two dependencies in your `build.gradle` file.

Your `Gradle`'s dependencies should look like:

```
dependencies {
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
 androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0'

 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
 androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
 androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
 androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
 contrib:2.2.2') {
    // Necessary to avoid version conflicts
    exclude group: 'javax.inject'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
  }


}
```

Hope it would help